How to specify the linker file to use with AS?
I am trying to build an application made of a single assembly file. I wrote a linker file targeting my chip which consists of a RISC-V CPU, a ROM and a RAM.
I don't know how to tell the AS program to use this linker file. When trying to run this Makefile:
AS      = ./xpack-riscv-none-elf-gcc-14.2.0-1/bin/riscv-none-elf-as.exe
OBJCOPY = ./xpack-riscv-none-elf-gcc-14.2.0-1/bin/riscv-none-elf-objcopy.exe

all : main.asm
    $(AS) main.asm -o instr.elf -T linker.ld
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary -j .text instr.elf instr.bin

I get the following output:
riscv-none-elf-as.exe: unrecognized option `-T'

What is the correct way to pass a linker file to the AS program ?

as is an assembler. You don't seem to be linking. ld is the linker.

Doesn't as call the linker like gcc does ? If not, then you're right I am not linking at all

No it does not. gcc calls as and ld.

gcc is a front-end, that invokes all the (needed) back-end tools in the proper order.  That may include the preprocessor, compiler, assembler, and linker (some of these may not be invoked depending on gcc command line args).  The back-end tools never invoke each other: they do one thing based on their command line options and exit.

If you use gcc -v foo.S, you'll see what commands it runs, including as and collect2.  (Where collect2 is a wrapper for ld)

I see, thank you everyone. Following your instructions, I updated the makefile and now it works, thanks again !

Please don't edit answers into questions.  Post it as an actual answer where it belongs, using the "answer my own question" button.  (Then revert the edit to your question.)

@PeterCordes got it, thanks

SOLUTION: quoting MadScientist:

"gcc is a front-end, that invokes all the (needed) back-end tools in
the proper order. That may include the preprocessor, compiler,
assembler, and linker (some of these may not be invoked depending on
gcc command line args). The back-end tools never invoke each other:
they do one thing based on their command line options and exit. "

So in fact I was not linking at all, the linker was not called in my Makefile because as.exe simply does not call it.
Here is the updated Makefile that now works, I changed several things but the line that was missing in the previous Makefile is line 10, where the linker specified in $(LD) is called:
AS      = ./xpack-riscv-none-elf-gcc-14.2.0-1/bin/riscv-none-elf-as.exe
LD      = ./xpack-riscv-none-elf-gcc-14.2.0-1/bin/riscv-none-elf-ld.exe
OBJCOPY = ./xpack-riscv-none-elf-gcc-14.2.0-1/bin/riscv-none-elf-objcopy.exe
OBJDUMP = ./xpack-riscv-none-elf-gcc-14.2.0-1/bin/riscv-none-elf-objdump.exe

all : main.asm
ifeq ($(wildcard ./bin),)
    mkdir -p ./bin
endif
    $(AS) main.asm -o ./bin/main.o
    $(LD) -o ./bin/main.elf ./bin/main.o -T linker.ld
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary -j .text ./bin/main.elf ./bin/instr.bin
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary -j .rodata ./bin/main.elf ./bin/rodata.bin
    $(OBJDUMP) -D -M no-aliases ./bin/main.elf > ./bin/main.dasm

Thanks again to everyone.
